# don't understand bebug.log file for running npm start on react project

Tags: reactjs, debugging, npm-start

Can someone help me explain how to read this debug.log file?
I am trying to run npm start for the react project.
I tried installing npm again by npm install, npm audit fix, then also
react-scripts start and nothing that I have tried seems working.

Here's the code below.

````
```
info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v12.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle website@0.1.0~prestart: website@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: website@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/inhyechoi/Desktop/InhyeChoi/react/inhyechoi-portfolio/inhyechoi.github.io/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
9 verbose lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/inhyechoi/Desktop/InhyeChoi/react/inhyechoi-portfolio/inhyechoi.github.io
10 silly lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle website@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: website@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid website@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/inhyechoi/Desktop/InhyeChoi/react/inhyechoi-portfolio/inhyechoi.github.io
16 verbose Darwin 19.4.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.9.0
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error website@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the website@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```
````

Comment: maybe try removing the local node_modules directory and then run ```npm install```?

Comment: @AdamJeliński  Thanks Adam, I did install fine, but I can't run npm start

Comment: Based on a quick search I did, this error could be related to a missing dependency, that's why completely re-downloading all of them sounded like a good thing to try. (running ```npm install``` with broken dependencies could just say that no dependencies need to be installed)

Comment: @AdamJeliński from my quick search npm ci seemed to be one of the solution i'll dig in more, but i'll keep ur recommendation in mind. thanks i'll tag u once i resolve it!

Comment: @AdamJelińskiso neither npm install / npm ci worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install yarn to see if it was working

`brew install yarn`

And I noticed both index.html / index.js file in the wrong place. So I put them in the correct folder and it worked!

So I uninstalled yarn by
`brew uninstall yarn`

and now using
`npm start`

to run the project.